# Is there any way to find out the type of block without breaking it?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there any way to get the type of a block (in textual form) without breaking it first when playing Minecraft on the Wii U?

First I was expecting that information to show up while holding the crosshair over a block.

Then, I was expecting that there'd be some key I could press while having the crosshairs over a block to get that information but there doesn't seem to be any key that does that.

Finally, I thought there may be some tool I could craft that would do that but haven't been able to find an answer to that, either.

I've looked at the help and searched online but have been unable to find an answer.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Im fairly sure that using the debug window (pressing F3 on windows) will show you. Open up that window and look at a specific block and I think it will show some info. I'm not in a position to test this ATM, and wont be for a few days. I'll post this as answer if when I can test this if it is true, and if someone else hasnt beaten me to the punch.

Comment: @Frank Yes I tried looking for an answer but I couldn't find one. I think the question is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Frank Nevertheless, I've added the stuff I've tried, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

1. In creative mode you can use the Pick Block keybind (middle mouse button) to put the block in your hand
2. The debug (F3) menu displays which block you're looking at

Note that method 1 will work in survival if you have the block in your inventory

Comment: That'll come handy for when I play Minecraft on a computer in the future, thank you. But forgot to mention that I'm playing on the Wii U at the moment :P

Answer (score 0):

If you’re playing the game for the first time on the console I text box containing the name and information of the block or entity you are looking at will come up the first time you look at it. I believe you can also turn on hints in the settings and information should come up again.